# Bash:Tail logs without junk characters

Tags: bash, tail

Running `tail -f /var/log/*` can sometimes show junk/garbage characters and trash the screen with control codes.

What's a good way to filter those out, in order to see a clean output with minimal loss of information?

Comment: Wait... you mean *literally* `tail -f /var/log/*`? Including the directories and the archived / gzipped files? Why would you want to do that? I'd start with `tail -f /var/log/*.log` and take it from there, *if* I'd want to funnel all the various logs through one `tail` in the first place...

Comment: Probably something like `find /var/log -type f -readable \( -name '*.log' -or -name dmesg -or -name syslog \) 2>/dev/null | xargs tail -f | sed $'s#\e[\[(][[:digit:]]*[[:print:]]##g' | strings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pipe to `sed`, to strip out ANSI codes (those likely to trash the console).
2. Pipe to `strings`, to only print actual strings, because some files in `/var/log/` contains binary data.

`tail -f /var/log/* | sed $'s#\e[\[(][[:digit:]]*[[:print:]]##g' | strings`

You can add these helper aliases to your shell profile by executing this:

```
cat >>~/.profile <<EOF

# ANSI codes stripping helpers
alias noansi="sed $'s#\e[\[(][[:digit:]]*[[:print:]]##g'"
alias noansistrings="noansi|strings"
EOF
. ~/.profile
```

Then for example, you will be able to run:

```
tail -f /var/log/* | noansistrings
```